# shadow notification on right side of the screen

Tags: notifications, screen, motorola-moto-g, notification-bar, motorola-moto-g-4g

I have a moto g4 plus and when I woke up today i saw that my right side of the phone is entirely covered with shadow of previous notifications I restarted the phone it won't go away input is working fine though
Here is a pic look closely to the right side
https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/fa3a64276a4b4489b0bc90f445aeddd1_A.png?a=answers&mr=0&x=1481432255&s=7587f59cf4fbfffe6d680c365028ae61

Comment: Well, I can't see anything wrong in the picture. Can we get a detailed one? (If possible - with more explanation.)

Comment: Enlarge the pic look on its right side there are shadows of notification on the right in slightly blue text

Comment: I'm 400% zoomed in right now and I still can't see the blue text. Can you doodle on the picture and post it (edit this post and then post the picture)?

Comment: I realize now that it is not visible in the screenshot I t is only visible to me because it is on my screen it is not affecting any thing inside the display

Comment: Damn. I was so fade up with my sight. Try uninstalling any recent apps you installed. Hope works!

Comment: Basically my screen has an imprint of different notifications time wifi  networks etc things which appear on top of the screen and it is in landscape mode it won't go away I didn't install anything it is showing time of 3.08 am yesterday it is really light text covering my whole right side of the screen

Answer (score 0):

The Moto G4 has an issue with screen retention. Basically when something is on the screen in the same place for a long time, it will "burn in" and leave an after-image for a few minutes.

It seems that Motorola shipped the G4 with a screen that doesn't deal with screen retention very well, and it especially happens when the screen is warm.

In the end I had to flash a custom kernel (ElementalX) to the phone and use CF.Lumen to reduce the "Daytime color filter" settings to R=0.769,G=0.769,B=0.769 with the KCAL driver. This reduced the chance of screen retention significantly for me in exchange for screen brightness, but it still happens when the screen gets really hot.